# Relationship between Outlook JS API and Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-restapi

I am looking to develop an addin for Outlook using the Office JS API. Reading the API documentation, there are a number of references to making a call to the Outlook REST API to do various things.

As an example, I want to retrieve a list of contacts from the local machine. I have seen posts suggesting I need to make a call to the Outlook REST API, however this doesn't make sense to me. If they are local/offline contacts, why would I need to do that? I feel as though I'm missing some relationship between the two.

A screenshot for the list of contacts I want to retrieve:

[image]

**Question**

Could someone outline how they fit together (if at all)? Is it expected that if I'm going to effectively use this API, I will also need to have my data "online", such that it's available from some REST service?

Comment: Please reference whatever posts you are talking about. Are 'local' contacts something that is specifically stored locally, or is it just some terminology, and in fact they are also stored online?

Comment: I don't see any mention of _personal_ contacts in this doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.contact?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: According to outlook they are stored locally, I've updated my post with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the contacts are stored locally it can not be retrieved using REST API. Getting the contacts via Office JS is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.